# Django forms: I want 'special' li among others :)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a listing of manufacturers in a form (TypedMultipleChoiceField plus CheckboxSelectMultiple widget).

Some of them are **recommended** (there is Manufaturers model and is_recommended field). And I want to give them special class.

So what I got:

```
<ul>
    <li>Just Audi</li>
    <li>Recommended BMW</li>
    <li>Just Skoda</li>
</ul>
```

What I want:

```
<ul>
    <li>Just Audi</li>
    <li class='recommended'>Recommended BMW</li>
    <li>Just Skoda</li>
</ul>
```

How can I add the class to the *special* li?

Comment: now I'm playing with widget - but during rendering I can't see item.is_recommended (it is to be taken from model)

Comment: you can render javascript code in your page to add this class to options: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-select-option-add-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the form fields on the template...

```
<ul>
{% for field in form %}
    {% for option in field.field.choices.queryset %}
        <li {% if option.is_recommended %}class="recommended"{% endif %}>
        {{ option.title }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own custom widget (inherit from `CheckBoxSelectMultiple`) to give your special item its flair.

In your special widget, override the `render` method - I have not tested it but something like this:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if value is None:
        value = ''
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
    # enter your condition here
    # if Foo.objects.get(name=name).is_recommended:
    # final_attrs['class'] = 'recommended'
    if value != '':
        # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
        final_attrs['value'] = force_unicode(self._format_value(value))
    return mark_safe(u'<input%s />' % self.flatatt(final_attrs))
```

Comment: the problem is that I got only unicodes in widget - and I need to check if the model field is True - then the class is applied. seems that I need to create a field - not a widget only